# Editing context xml file in spring at runtime

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a bean definition which has set and map fields. The fields are populated from context.xml at startup. sample context file look like below.

```
<bean id="beana" class="com.example.BeanA">

    <property name="dates">
        <set>
            <value>2012-12-25</value>
            <value>2012-12-26</value>        

    </set>
        </property>

        <property name="hours">
            <map>
                <entry key="1" value="09:00-18:00"/>        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

At runtime some new items are added to these(dates) set and map(hours) and I want to persist them to applicationcontext.xml for next startups. My question is there a shortcut in spring for this(serialising the bean to xml) or basic xml processing is the only option?

Comment: So, the new items are added to xml?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: If the items are written to xml then, wouldn't that file be available during next startup?